# Prime counting function

Tags: prime-numbers

How much of an impact would the discovery of an exact formula that is equivalent to the prime counting function have on the mathematics community and acedemia as a whole?

Comment: Depends on how complicated the formula is, I'd guess.

Comment: Say an elementary function that can be easily computed

Answer (score 3):

The important thing is to keep yourself hidden. To my certain knowledge, three people found such a formula in the last twenty years. One in Berlin, one in Beijing, and one in Rio de Janeiro. All were found dead, with the brief version of the Riemann-Siegel Formula carved into their foreheads. There are those who cannot afford to let this knowledge become public.

Comment: Bruh is it serious issue?